# How to get an span from its textnode or text content?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form with 3 fields:

```
            <form id="book-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="author">Author</label>
              <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the author of the book">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
              <input type="text" name="isbn" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the book isbn">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Book to store</button>
        </form>
```

Here are I am retrieving the value of these fields that I will insert in their respective span in the html.

```
const title = document.getElementsByName('title')[0].value
const author = document.getElementsByName('author')[0].value
const isbn = document.getElementsByName('isbn')[0].value
```

Now I have three span tags where the value of these form fields are suppose to be inserted.

```
<span class="title">// the value of title</span>
<span class="author">// the value of author</span>
<span class="isbn">// the value of isbn</span>
```

Now I have a function that checks if the retrieve from the fields of the form is not empty(null) if that is the case I want to remove the span that is was suppose to be in the dom.

```
function insertMe(fieldValue) {
if (fieldValue === "") {
    // How to remove the span that it was suppose to go
} else {
    return fieldValue
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you check if you want to insert it, before inserting? something like `if (notEmptySpan(title)) insert(title)`

Comment: yup that's possible but these span has margins and this will mess all the html used by django in the backend.

Comment: What's the difference between _not inserting_ (my suggestion) and _removing after inserting_ (what I understand is what you want)?

Comment: If you do not insert it you will be left by the margin of the style of the span which is not the case when you remove the span it self there will be no space left because this is part of another div which I cut.

Comment: you can use .remove() after dom selection . for example  document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].remove();

Comment: If you do not insert it you will be left by the margin of the style of the span which is not the case when you remove the span it self there will be no space left because this is part of another div which I cut.

Comment: @Ginish this will remove the input in the form I think.

Comment: @Ginish now How to select span that you need to remove is my concern here.

Comment: @Sahish Pass the element (or at least the classname) to the `insertMe` function as a parameter. There's no way around that.

Comment: @bergi yes I think this would be better approch just thought I can do by knowin the text node

Comment: @Sahish I have used getElementsByClassName not getElementsByName. It will check css class having title. and it won't remove input.

Comment: @Sahish Sure, you can also pass the text node that is contained in the element, but that's more complicated. Either way, you have to pass an additional parameter to `insertMe`, not just the string value.

Comment: @Ginish yup you are definitly right sorry did not pay attention to it

Comment: @Bergi yup gotcha I think passing the element is simpler I just was wondering if there is any possiblity to do this just using the textnode.

Comment: @Sahish yes, there is. Can you show us your attempt? Can you show us how you would do it by passing the element? Please [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: Let me explain before moving to the editor, I will get the parent div of the spans since they have the same parent and loop through the children (spans) if the textnode is an empty string then I will remove through the function hope that make sens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you're calling `insertMe`, and the name of that function is misleading because you're only removing elements, not adding them.

I'd approach it this way.

When the button is clicked/onSubmit call the function and use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the inputs by class. Iterate over them and if the value is an empty string [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) the span whose class matches the name of the input, otherwise set the text content of the span to the input value.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
  inputs.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    const el = document.querySelector(`span.${name}`);
    if (el && !value) {
      el.remove();
    } else {
      el.textContent = value;
    }
  });
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter a title">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" placeholder="Enter an author">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter an ISBN number">
<button>Click</button>
<br/><br/>
<span class="title">Title</span><br/>
<span class="author">Author</span><br/>
<span class="isbn">ISBN</span><br/>
```